# Проблема компиляции(Ненормальное программирование)

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

template <class F, class G>
auto operator*(F&& f, G&& g) -> decltype(auto) {
    return [=](auto ...args) { return f(g(args...)); };
}


int main() {

    auto f = [](auto x, auto y) -> decltype(auto) {
        return x + y;
    };

    //Если определить функцию так, то все прекрасно работает
    auto g = [](auto x) -> decltype(auto) {
        return x / x;
    }; 

    //Hо если определить функцию таким способом, то огромные листинги ошибки компиляции в случае комплексных чисел      
    //  auto g = [](auto x) -> decltype(auto) {
    //      return x * x;
    //  }; 

    std::cout << "Result " << (g * f)(2, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Result " << (g * f)(2.1f, 3.0f)  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Result " << (g * f)(std::complex<double>{1.0, 2.0}, std::complex<double>{0.0, 2.0}) <<std::endl;


}
```

Comment: Наверное, дело в вашем `auto operator*`, но это не точно -- ошибку компиляции вы в вопрос не добавили :)

Comment: Немножко вспомогательных классов, и можно будет соорудить SFINAE, которое не позволит устраивать композицию натуральных чисел.

Answer (score 0):

Определяя *глобальный* оператор * вы сразу ломаете прорву кода. Оберните его в собственное пространство имен и все должно заработать:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

namespace my_namespace
{

template <class F, class G>
auto operator*(F&& f, G&& g) -> decltype(auto) {
    return [=](auto ...args) { return f(g(args...)); };
}

}

int main() {
    auto f = [](auto x, auto y) -> decltype(auto) {
        return x + y;
    };

    //Hо если определить функцию таким способом, то огромные листинги ошибки компиляции в случае комплексных чисел      
    auto g = [](auto x) -> decltype(auto) {
        return x * x;
    }; 

    std::cout << "Result " << my_namespace::operator *(g, f)(std::complex<double>{1.0, 2.0}, std::complex<double>{0.0, 2.0}) <<std::endl;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/odFb34oLYf1cqndc)